# The use of hundreds of thousands

Tags: verbs

Which verb form follows the phrase 'hundreds of thousands' while denoting an infinite amount of money? 
Do we write:

> Not hundreds of thousands **are** spent...

OR:

> Not hundreds of thousands **is** spent

Comment: It should be *are* for the simple reason that the actual subject, *hundreds*, is a plural noun.

Comment: I wouldn't use that construct at all; I would say: _hundreds of thousands weren't spent_